# htaccess url variable issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm having a small issue.

I have my index.php page as a base page for all of my pages data stored in the database. I'm using this htaccess to rewrite all of my pages, excluding posts from the blog.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#ALL STANDARD PAGES
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,NC,L]

#TRIED ALL THESE, NO LUCK
#RewriteRule (.*) index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
#RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]

#ALL SPECIAL POSTING PAGES
RewriteRule    ^/posts/([0-9]+)/?$    view_post.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

This works perfectly for any page I have without variables on the url.

Example:

> www.mysite.com/home  | |  www.mysite.com/contact

All of these load perfectly. But if I add any variables the page crashes for a 404.

Example:

> www.mysite.com/contact?email=sent

I'm not really sure what to do, I've tried searching for guides online to teach me the proper syntax, googling if others have had the same issues, so far nothing has brought any luck.

Please help.

Comment: did you used `QSA` flag?

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar I just tried it with this. but it didn't work still.
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]

Comment: well try it on this rule `^/posts/([0-9]+)/?$` not on the `index.php`

Comment: That's the issue I'm having is with the main pages, not on the post pages. :/

Comment: I want my contact and home and about pages to be able to accept variables for GET values.

Comment: Your rule `RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,NC,L]` should work (although you don't need a capture group since you are not using it).  Try tracing the rewrite in the Apache error log, you can turn on logging with `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` in your httpd.conf. This will show you the exact path apache is rewriting to when there is a query string. A separate problem is you'll need to put your `^/posts` rule before the index.php rule, otherwise the rewrite will never make it to /posts.

Comment: As @Vrac commented above `/contact?email=sent` shouldn't give 404 with above rules. What is your Apache version and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Vrac, I put them in the right order. And my .htaccess is located in the root folder for the domain. I'm going to look into my apache log here asap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please comment out previous cond for checking i am assuming you are rewriting these requests `www.mysite.com/contact` to index.php page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```